# Mono on Linux plus MVC3: Root directory shows file/folder list on web browser

Tags: linux, asp.net-mvc-3, ubuntu, mono, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm struggling getting my MVC3 site I developed on Windows to correctly run on Linux (Ubuntu) and Apache using Mono 2.10.5.

When I browse to the site root via my web browser, I see my file/folder structure instead of the home page of the site, which appears to me as though routing is not working. Everything works fine on my development environment on Windows.

When in this view, if I click on Global.asax, for instance, I see the standard ASP.NET "yellow screen of death" (YSOD) with a 500 error stating "Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute' from assembly 'MyWebSite'.".

On the bottom of the YSOD, I see the following: **Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.5 (Debian 2.10.5-1); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1**

I've followed the instructions for configuring Mono for MVC3 here: http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/06/get-mvc3-razor-running-on-mono/

Does anyone have any clues as to why the file/folder structure is being listed when I visit the site root from my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that mono was running under port 8080, and I couldn't configure it to run on port 80 due to a conflict with another module. I am able to run things fine on port 8080 now.